# How to see officeapp in office365( both desktop and web view)

Tags: web-applications, desktop-application, visual-studio-2013, office365-apps, office-app

How to see an office app in office365(both desktop and web).
I'm getting an error when I upload in office365 web app "App Warning This app is not available in the Web App. Open this document in desktop version of Office to use the app".

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or related activities.

Answer (score 0):

Not all types of apps (task pane app, mail app, content app) are viewable in all Office clients/web apps. The [current compatibility list](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj220082.aspx#StartBuildingApps_AnatomyofApp) for each type of app is as follows:

**Task pane apps**

- Excel 2013
- Excel Web App
- Word 2013
- PowerPoint 2013
- Project 2013

**Content apps**

- Excel 2013
- Excel Web App

**Mail apps**

- Outlook 2013
- Outlook Web App
- OWA for Devices

The error *"App Warning: This app is not available in the Web App. Open this document in desktop version of Office to use the app"* is generally an indicator you are trying to use an app that can be used in the desktop version of the client but not in the web version.